# Where does scarface pasta get its name from?

Tags: chicken, pasta, italian-cuisine

I couldn't find anything within the first few pages of a Google search other than the fact that fettuccine al burro (it's original name) was named after it's creator Alfredo Di Lelio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scarface was the nickname of the early 20th century American organized crime boss, Al Capone. He was slashed in the face while working at a New York City nightclub. The injury left a scar that led to the nickname.

[image]

Capone's parents immigrated from Italy, and it is said that he enjoyed eating Italian foods. The notoriety and name-recognition of Al Capone (a.k.a. Scarface) has resulted in it being chosen, in one form or another, as the name for many restaurants and pizza parlors over the years.

Naming a dish "Scarface Pasta" is but a natural extension of that line of marketing. It is however, merely someone's suggestion of what Al Capone might have ordered — something that sounds cute on a menu, but may actually be nothing more than spaghetti with sauce.